# How to apply filter to magento model before loading or selecting the item?

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I am a newbie in magento development and want to implement softdelete on my models . So basically I have added a is_deleted field in tables. So when I delete any record I just set is_deleted to 1.  Now my question is that if I select record(s)  from either model or resource Model only filtered record where is_deleted is 0 should come.  For Exmaple - $model->load($id) should return the record which is not soft deleted.  Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model you would need to override Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::load() function.

If the soft delete is on all models you need to override:
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract::load() method to something like:

```
public function load(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object, $value, $field = null)
{
    if (is_null($field)) {
        $field = $this->getIdFieldName();
    }

    $read = $this->_getReadAdapter();
    if ($read && !is_null($value)) {
        $select = $this->_getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object);
        $data = $read->fetchRow($select);

        if ($data && $data[is_delete] != 1) {
            $object->setData($data);
        }
    }

    $this->unserializeFields($object);
    $this->_afterLoad($object);

    return $this;
}
```

Here is how you could override an abstract class in Magento:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739628/override-extend-magento-abstract-class

Comment: Hi Paras,  Thanks for the help I was looking for same code.

Answer (score 2):

```
$model = Mage::getModel('modulename/modelname')->getCollection()
         ->addFieldToFilter('is_deleted',0);
```

this code give a query like this

```
select * from yourtablename where (is_deleted= '0')
```

This **$model** will return only that data where **is_deleted = 0**

Comment: Hi Thanks for help but I was looking for a generalized way where it may be applied to all models

Comment: Just A little question that What should I do If I want to display the items in grid without applying AddFieldtoFilter using the load function logic ?

Comment: you want to get data using load($id) ri8? if yes than it will return only single row data please clarify what you want and using AddFieldtoFilter what's your problem

Comment: I just want to implement softdelete in models so when I get result set either using load or in grid view is should be filtered by is_deleted coloum.

Comment: have you any unique id? and using that id you can get data which is  filtered by is_deleted and in grid view you want data filtered by is_deleted coloum than write code in  **_prepareCollection()**